# Is it possible to pass node process variable to webpack builded package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iis, webpack, iisnode

I am currently developing nodejs app which will be hosted on iis, using iisnode.
I am having such a problem, this is part of my server.js:

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

process.env.PORT is passed by IIS, so at the moment when I locally building webpack package I have no port.

I deploy the build-ed package on my server, but looking at server.bundle.js, I can see:

```
app.listen(undefined);
```

now IIS can not start the application..

Is there any option to set webpack bundle-ed package to expect node process variable to be passed on the run?

Or maybe I am doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)